# Application Icon Not Displayed In Android

Tags: android, icons, screen

I have added my application in Share Menu .It is working perfectly When i am running the application. But application icon is not displaying in screen.Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/gdrivelogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.vishwak.gdrive.activities.GDriveLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>                             
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />                
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity  android:name="com.vishwak.gdrive.activities.MainActivity"></activity>
  </application>
```

Comment: android:icon="@drawable/gdrivelogo" place your icon in drawable folder

Comment: ok... You want see your icon on Action bar or in menu

Comment: No Brother. Application is not displaying in screen. When i remove <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />   then only it is displaying.

Comment: ok.. i got ur problem

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.vishwak.gdrive.activities.GDriveLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter> 
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />  
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />              
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

to solve that issue.